# How to validate list in mongodb schema?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, jsonschema

I'm creating HOME collection validation where I have rooms type(double, single, ensuite) and validation should allow adding all items listed.

```
"rooms.type": {bsonType: ["ensuite", "double", "single"]},
```

This is what I have in the validator

```
db.createCollection("home", { 
validator : {
    $jsonSchema : {
    bsonType: "object",
    required: ["address.line1", "address.town", "rooms.type", 
    "rooms.qty", "rooms.price"],
 properties: {
    "address.line1": {bsonType: "string"},
    "address.town": {bsonType: "string"},
    "rooms.type": {bsonType: ["ensuite", "double", "single"]},
    "rooms.qty": {bsonType: "int", minimum: 0},
    "rooms.price": {bsonType: ["double"], minimum: 0},
}}}})
```

I'm getting an error that

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unknown type name alias: ensuite",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"
```

I expect array room.type to allow one or all attributes in the group specified in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that the type of `rooms.type` should be "array", with minimum 1 item in the array, and that each item of that array should be an enum as follows:

```
"rooms.type": {
    type: "array",
    minItems: 1,
    items: {
        enum: ["ensuite", "double", "single"]
    }
}
```

MongoDB has [documentation on $jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema) but you can find a bit more detail in the [JSON Schema validation spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00) linked to from the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the schema this way:

```
db.createCollection('home', {
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: 'object',
      required: ['address', 'rooms'],
      properties: {
        address: {
          bsonType: 'object',
          additionalProperties: false,
          required: ['line1', 'town'],
          properties: {
            line1: {
              bsonType: 'string'
            },
            town: {
              bsonType: 'string'
            }
          }
        },
        rooms: {
          bsonType: 'object',
          additionalProperties: false,
          required: ['type', 'qty', 'price'],
          properties: {
            type: {
              bsonType: 'string',
              enum: ["ensuite", "double", "single"]
            },
            qty: {
              bsonType: 'int',
              minimum: 0
            },
            price: {
              bsonType: 'array',
              items: {
                bsonType: 'double',
                minimum: 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```